# Blackberry background image?

Tags: blackberry, background

I have searched but haven't find out any solution, i have but its creating problems. when I insert this it says illegal argument and doesn't start.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("Background.png");

 this.getMainManager().setBackground(

             BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(bitmap)
         );
```

It doesn't work.

Thanks for helping! Its working. Just a typo error of my path

Comment: you want to add fields to this image ?

Comment: No I just want to set a background

Comment: I mean yes there will be labels and some fields infront of this background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tyy this -

```
final Bitmap top = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("your background image.png");
final VerticalFieldManager top_ = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH){

        public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, top.getWidth(),
                    top.getHeight(), top, 0, 0);
            super.paint(graphics);
        }

    };
```

Now you add all your fields to this top_. then add the top_ to your screen. If there is no fields, it will not display the background image. so Dont forget to add some fields.

Comment: I have now many fields with different layouts in it. Can't it can be done in another way? because Im using 2 or 3 vertical and horizontal managers. :S And I already have made 16 classes. I though to add the background at the end. Any idea how to resolve this now?

Comment: add all your items to this VerticalFieldManager .Then add it to your screen.

Comment: Yes its working but its filled half. How can I get it to 100% width and 100% height?

Comment: either use Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH and Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT or set margin.